# R datatable in DT the shiny filter "none" option doesn't work

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have just switched to using dataTables in my shiny app. In the ui, I have `dataTableOutput("affordabilityTable")` in a mainPanel and the following renderDataTable in the server

```
output$affordabilityTable <- renderDataTable({
    dt <- data.table::copy(data.afford())
    dt <- DT::datatable(dt, options = list(autoHideNavigation = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, filter = "none"))
#   dt <- DT::datatable(dt, options = list(dom = 't',ordering = F))
dt
})
```

The commented code works, in the sense that it turns off filtering, column sorting, etc. It does leave row numbers in the first column which I can't figure out how to get rid of. The uncommented datatable line leaves all the filter features showing.

The code I have included is not complete enough to reproduce the problem with row numbers but I'm hoping there is some fix that is obvious to someone with some datatable experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rownames` parameter is part of `datatable` call, not inside the `options`. Or more specifically

```
dt <- DT::datatable(dt, rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't',ordering = F))
```

I knew this is confusing. You can think that the `options` are the original js module `datatable` parameters, while there are some other parameters added by `DT::datatable`.

Comment: My original attempt was with `dt <- DT::datatable(dt, autoHideNavigation = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, filter = c("none"))`; in other words with autoHideNavigation, row names, and filter as datatable parameters. The resulting table has all the filter elements (search field, column sort, etc.) still visible. So I tried the options to be passed to the js module, also without success.

Comment: Did you try `dt <- DT::datatable(dt, rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't',ordering = F))`?

Comment: I had not tried that. It works! If you make this an answer I'll mark it as the best!

Comment: @JerryN I has added the example to the answer.